# Handle 404 error with Express 4

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express 4 and I have about 50 html pages. I'm trying to handle 404 errors but can't figure out how. I don't want to manually define all the routers within node. Is there a way to dynamically redirect to a 404 Jade template if a page doesn't exist?

I tried this code but didn't work:

```
app.enable('verbose errors');
app.set('port', 3000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/html/'));

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('ONLINE !');
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('GET ' + req.originalUrl)
    console.log('At %d', Date.now());
    next();
});

// Handle 404
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.accepts('html') && res.status(404)) {
        res.render('404.jade');
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: Dynamically how? You'll need to define a route somehow, be it with the router, `app.use`, `app.error` or middleware etc? Are all your files static, you don't seem to have any routes other than the static ones, and it looks like all your dynamic requests would end up in the 404 handler ?

Comment: Yes they are all statics. I have a few get and post requests but that's for an API I am building on the side. If I set up a middleware, all the requests end up in 404 errors.

Comment: So even the static ones end up in the 404 route? You should `listen` after the routes are defined, so move that line to the bottom

Comment: As @adeneo says follow the order in my answer. It works for me. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work for me. The post and get requests are fine, only the static files end up in the 404 route if I sent it up like @shansfk did.

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.get('/employee', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Employee route !!');
});


// Handle 404 - Keep this as a last route
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404);
    res.send('404: File Not Found');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Folder structure,

[image]

Now when we issue the request like this

> http://localhost:3000/sample

This has been handled by the middleware.

**UPDATE**

The way to show the html files without writing the **get request** is just another middleware like this

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('views'));
```

Add the 'views' middleware exactly after the 'public'.

Now if we give

> http://localhost:3000/index.html

The page is rendered.

Comment: The problem is that I have 50 HTML pages, I don't want to create a get request for all of them. Unless I have to.

Comment: Kindly check this. Is this fine? Apologies if I misunderstood you. I am sorry !

Comment: I am glad that it helps you. :)

Comment: It worked. But why status 400? It has to be 404 right?

Comment: when i put this as a last route i got  Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to redirect then u can simply use this:

```
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).redirect('/MyHomepage')
});
```

Comment: after set this code every api return homepage

Answer (score 0):

Very simple you can add this middleware

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!")
})
```